# Ideas on building a generic microservice for secrets

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We're attempting to build a generic microservice for secrets into our HashiCorp Vault. We'd like it to be generic enough that other teams within the company can use it as well as our own team. We will REQUIRE AppRole security and policies on each and every secret store and will also be building our own trusted orchestrator for the AppRole Tokens.

How would we need to setup the URL's for it to be generic enough to allow everyone to be able to access only their own secrets? I was thinking something like this:

```
machinename.servicename.local/roleId/secretId/nameSpace/secretsPath
```

Obviously it would be a POST vs. a GET because it would be machine to machine with no human interaction at all.

Comment: The secretId is... secret. If it shows in the URL you will end up with logs full of credentials. Anything based on organisation is bound to break at the next reorg. I would consider something like `environment/application-id/stage/any-name-from-here`. So you would have `non-production/1234/dev/database-password` and `non-production/1234/uat/database-password`, as well as `production/1234/disaster-recovery/database-password`.

Comment: We have decided to use environment variables on our servers to store the secretIDs and set them to be seen only by the authorized user that runs the service. Essentially, they would pass the NAME of the environment variable to pull the secretID from.